# How to put list entries that contain "Error" in another list?

Tags: c#, list, search, contains, binary-search

I am writing a program in visual c# to filter error messages from a .log file and display them. There is a list named "contentList" and there's a list named "errorList"

```
void BtnCheckLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchForErrors(_ContentListLeft);
}

void BtnCheckRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchForErrors(_ContentListRight);
}

void SearchForErrors(List<string> contentList)
{
    int searchIndex = 1;
    List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
    while(searchIndex != errorList.Count)
    {
        var bla = contentList.BinarySearch("Error");
        searchIndex += 1;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Following errors were spotted:\n\n" + errorList.ToString() + "\n \n \n", "placeholder", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

contentList contains every line of the chosen .log file, now I want to put all entries that contain the word error in the list "errorList" and display it. My problem is that the BinarySearch finds nothing, bla (my placeholder var) is constantly -1 and I don't know another way to manage this.
Maybe you know why the BinarySearch finds nothing or you know another way to display the error lines.

Comment: Without having any clue on your data within the list, how do you expect us to guess why nothing is found? I´d guess you don´t need to search for the **element** `"Error"`, but for an element **containing** `"Error"`: `contentList.Where(x => x.Contains("Error"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your log file is a text file then you can do something like this:

```
string result = string.Empty;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("myLogFile.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if(line.Contains("Error"))
    {
        errorList.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`BinarySearch` will search for an **entire element**, not parts of it. So if you have a line like `"This is an Error"`, `BinarySearch` will return `-1`, because the line does not **equal** the string `"Error"`, but just **contains** it.

What you want instead is to check if any of the elements **contains** the word `"Error"`:

```
var errorLines = contentList.Where(x => x.Contains("Error"));
```

Comment: plus one for linq. That was really simple

Answer (score 0):

I may not be familiar with BinaryList but here is some help from a foreach loop..

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
            List<string> newList = new List<string>();
            errorList.Add("one error");
            errorList.Add("some text");
            errorList.Add("two error");
            errorList.Add("some text");
            errorList.Add("some text");
            errorList.Add("some text");
            errorList.Add("three error");
            errorList.Add("four error");
            errorList.Add("some text");
            errorList.Add("some text");
            foreach(string item in errorList){
                if(item.Contains("error")){
                    newList.Add(item);
                }
            }

            foreach(string item in newList){
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps !